# Component not showing up in React

Tags: reactjs

I added one more component  to show the type of comment in preexisting code but its not showing up. Any idea why? I have put it in the props object and am referring to it in the render code exactly as it should be rendered. What might i be doing wrong? The rest of the code is an example from FB documentation and it works just fine. Only my component is not rendering.

```
    function formatDate(date) {
  return date.toLocaleDateString();
}

function Comment(props) {
  return (
    <div className="Comment">
      <div className="UserInfo">
        <img className="Avatar"
             src={props.author.avatarUrl}
             alt={props.author} />
        <div className="UserInfo-name">
          <h1>{props.author.naam}
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Comment-text">
        {props.text}
      </div>
      <div className="Comment-type">
        {props.type}
      </div>
      <div className="Comment-date">
        {formatDate(props.date)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const comment = {
  date: new Date(),
  text: 'I hope you enjoy learning React seriously!',
  type: 'Positive',
  author: {
    naam: 'Hello Kitty',
    avatarUrl: 'http://placekitten.com/g/64/64'
  }
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Comment
    date={comment.date}
    text={comment.text}
    author={comment.author} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Do you have another ReactDOM.render() method in your code?

Comment: No, but that answered by question. I needed to add it to my render function,

Comment: ReactDOM.render(
  <Comment
    date={comment.date}
    text={comment.text}
    type={comment.type}
    author={comment.author} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: when i add the type={comment.type} it works. Thanks!!!